# Firebase data grid view items repeat in the grid view

Tags: android, gridview

Please review my code. 
This code actually fetches values from Firebase and appends it to the grid view, although I found that gridView updates with the duplicate values but the onclick listener executes properly giving only unique values.

The gridView has repeated values and it appears to be changing randomly.
It would be helpful if anyone could help me through some sample working code. Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

```
public class Materials extends Fragment {
    private Button btnTEST;
    Context context;
    CardView cardview;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams;
    TextView textview;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    GridView grid;
    int l=0,fl=0;
    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_materials, container, false);

        context = v.getContext();

        grid=(GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid);


        final String[] web=new String[13];

        final int[] imageId = new int[13];


        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Materials_management_new/Materials/");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (fl == 0) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        web[l] =snap.getKey().toString();
                        l++;
                        fl=1;

                    }

                    //= gson.toJson(dataSnapshot);
                    //  Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, json, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                CustomGrid adapter;
                adapter = new CustomGrid(getContext(), web, imageId);
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });

     //   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUccesssssafmlnfka", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



        return v;
    }



}
```

And this is my custom grid code

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(web[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your CustomGrid class ?

Comment: @Aswath, Did you check the value and length of `web` before passing that into Adapter here `adapter = new CustomGrid(getContext(), web, imageId);`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have an ordered list of items, you can sort it using the database query, additionally setting the rules for the database to be indexed, otherwise the entire installation will be done on the client side.

See Sorting and filtering data in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?authuser=1